# MySQL Join And Select Random Field

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to join two tables and return a random field from the second table because there are multiple matches when joining.

For example. I have a `users` table and a `user_posts` table. I want to select each user's `id`, and a random post `id` and the post's `message` that they have in the `user_posts` table. Each user can have multiple posts in the `user_posts` table.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28515068) explains what I'm trying to do, but it's not working. Here's my query:

```
SELECT user_id, post_id, message FROM (
    SELECT users.id AS user_id, user_posts.id AS post_id, message
    FROM users INNER JOIN user_posts ON users.id = user_id
    ORDER BY RAND()
) AS a GROUP BY user_id
```

For testing, I added two rows in the `user_posts` table for user with `id` of 1 but it's retrieving the same post every time.

Answer (score 0):

using cross apply to get random one post and join to users to display

```
 select u.id,RandomPostbyUser.* 
     from users u
     cross apply (     
        SELECT  user_posts.id AS post_id, message
        FROM users u1 INNER JOIN user_posts ON u1.id = u.id
        order by RAND()
        LIMIT 1) RandomPostbyUser
```

Comment: I don't understand, this doesn't even compile?

Comment: Working now, but it returns all posts for each user. I just want one random one.

Comment: can you test again. since you only want 1

Comment: Sorry, I want one random post for each user, not just one user's random post.

Comment: try again mate.

Comment: I'm using MySQL which doesn't have cross apply. Do you know of how to get it working with MySQL?

Comment: You can check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869221/cross-outer-apply-in-mysql