# Create two alias for table

Tags: mysql, alias

How can I create two aliases for a table containing a `,` separator in MySQL?

For example:

```
SELECT b.*,a.* FROM `tbl_users` a,b where a.id=b.parent_id.
```

Comment: you'll probably have to clarify your question along with adding a few examples of things you tried in order to receive any help. You can always update your question. Welcome to stack overflow, recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `SELECT b.*,a.* FROM tbl_users a, tbl_users b where a.id=b.parent_id`? Whatever good this may do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create a table alias in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890155/how-do-i-create-a-table-alias-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are doing some self join and you can do as

```
select
a.*,b.* from tbl_users a
left join tbl_users b on a.id=b.parent_id
```

If you only want matching records then make it an `inner join` instead of `left join`