# is it possible to create a database-wide alias for a table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have a table named "meetings" for historic reasons, and a lot of code that references that table name.

I want to rename it to "jobs" to match what we've been calling it for the last 8 years.

renaming the table will break the code.

Is there a way to create a database-wide alias so I can rename the table to "jobs", but code that references "meetings" will still work?

the code is for inserts and reads.

Comment: Create a view from the table and call it meetings if you do not need to modify it

Comment: possible duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890155/how-do-i-create-a-table-alias-in-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890155/how-do-i-create-a-table-alias-in-mysql)

Comment: note that I *specifically* stated that the code is for *inserts and reads*. obviously updates and deletes as well.

a view is not the answer

Comment: Would using something like ProxySQL be an option or would it not be viable?

Comment: I may be wrong about views. my knowledge of them is about 20 years old and I don't remember being able to edit them.

a proxy server might be a possible answer, yes. so would a versioned API (more work). I was really just hoping for a way to say "table A is also called B"